# get previous from max value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have folowing sql query an di want to get previous of max value from table.

```
select max(card_no),vehicle_number
FROM WBG.WBG_01_01
group by vehicle_number
```

Through this query i got each maximum card number of each vehicle.But i want to get previouse of that max.For example

if vehicle number has card number `21,19,17,10,5,6,1` and i want to get `19` from `max` function

Please anyone tell me how can i do this in sql.

Comment: Unless there is a known way of ordering the cards, I don't think what you want is possible. How is the order of `21, 17, 19, 10, 5, 6, 1` determined?

Comment: @ninesided what makes it impossible?

Comment: Looks like you're actually looking for `19` or clearly you're missing something in your question...

Comment: @Shaheer because ordered numerically the next highest value to the max is 19, not 17 as the question states. This means that the order that the cards appear in is important but unknown! Either that, or the question is wrong and the correct answer is 19.

Comment: oh now i get it, you are right about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
select max(card_no),vehicle_number
FROM WBG.WBG_01_01
where card_no < (Select max(card_no) from WBG.WBG_01_01 group by vehicle_number)
group by vehicle_number
```

Comment: This selects the very maximum `card_no` irrespective of the vehicle_number it is grouped with. I don't think that's what he's looking for.

Comment: Because there are more than one cards which are less that max card no .u got ?

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to use analytics, something like this:

```
select
    vehicle_number,
    prev_card_no
from (
    select 
        card_no, 
        vehicle_number,
        lag(card_no) over 
            (partition by vehicle_number order by card_no) as prev_card_no,
        max(card_no) over
            (partition by vehicle_number) as max_card_no
    FROM WBG.WBG_01_01
)
where max_card_no = card_no;
```

Of course, this doesn't take into account your seemingly arbitrary ordering from your question, nor would it work with duplicate maximum numbers.